# Color overlay on div with opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three divs like this next to each other:

[image]

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col col--lg-4 col--md-6">
    <div class="reserved__inner">
        <img src="images/image1.png" alt="" />
        <div class="reserved__text">
            <h3 class="first">Lorem ipsum</h3>
            <p>lorem ipsum text</p>
            <a href="#" class="button">Link 1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col col--lg-4 col--md-6">
    <div class="reserved__inner">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <img src="images/image2.png" alt="" />
        <div class="reserved__text">
            <h3 class="first">Lorem ipsum</h3>
            <p>lorem ipsum text</p>
            <a href="#" class="button">Link 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col col--lg-4 col--md-6">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="reserved__inner">
        <img src="images/image3.png" alt="" />
        <div class="reserved__text">
            <h3 class="first">Lorem ipsum</h3>
            <p>lorem ipsum text</p>
            <a href="#" class="button">Link 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I also have a `p element` and `a element` in my div but those are hidden. In my javascript file I have this:

```
$('.reserved__inner').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).find('h3').addClass('black');
        $(this).find('p').show();
        $(this).find('a').show();

    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).find('h3').removeClass('black');
        $(this).find('p').hide();
        $(this).find('a').hide();
    }
});
```

When you hover on this you get this:

[image]

But now I would also like to have an overlay on the image when you hover on it. Like this:

[image]

My CSS looks currently like this:

```
.reserved__inner {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 380px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.reserved__inner img {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto!important;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: auto!important;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    bottom: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    right: -9999px;
    margin: auto;
}

.reserved__text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 56px 54px 50px 58px;
    /*cursor: pointer;*/
}

.reserved__text h3 {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    line-height: 35px;
}

.reserved__text h3 sup {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.reserved__text h3.first {
    color: #fff;
}

.reserved__text p {
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

But I'm really stuck on how I can create the color overlay. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this fairly easily by thinking a bit differently.

Just add a background color to the `.reserved_inner` class, then lower the opacity of the image itself.

```
.reserved__inner {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 380px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
     background: #a00; /* add a background color here */
}

.reserved__inner img {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto!important;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: auto!important;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    bottom: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    right: -9999px;
    margin: auto;
     opacity: .5; /* Lower the image opacity here */
}
```

```js
$('.reserved__inner').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).find('h3').addClass('black');
        $(this).find('p').show();
        $(this).find('a').show();
      $(this).children('img').css({opacity: '.3'}); /* Changes image opacity */

    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).find('h3').removeClass('black');
        $(this).find('p').hide();
        $(this).find('a').hide();
      $(this).children('img').css({opacity: '.5'});/* Changes image opacity */
    }
});
```

```css
.reserved__inner {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 380px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  background: #a00; /* add a background color here */
}

.reserved__inner img {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto!important;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: auto!important;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    bottom: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    right: -9999px;
    margin: auto;
  opacity: .5; /* Lower the iamge opacity here */
}

.reserved__text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 56px 54px 50px 58px;
    /*cursor: pointer;*/
}

.reserved__text h3 {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    line-height: 35px;
}

.reserved__text h3 sup {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.reserved__text h3.first {
    color: #fff;
}

.reserved__text p {
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

<div class="col col--lg-4 col--md-6">
    <div class="reserved__inner">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/380/200" alt="" />
        <div class="reserved__text">
            <h3 class="first">Lorem ipsum</h3>
            <p>lorem ipsum text</p>
            <a href="#" class="button">Link 1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col col--lg-4 col--md-6">
    <div class="reserved__inner">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/380/200" alt="" />
        <div class="reserved__text">
            <h3 class="first">Lorem ipsum</h3>
            <p>lorem ipsum text</p>
            <a href="#" class="button">Link 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col col--lg-4 col--md-6">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="reserved__inner">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/380/200" alt="" />
        <div class="reserved__text">
            <h3 class="first">Lorem ipsum</h3>
            <p>lorem ipsum text</p>
            <a href="#" class="button">Link 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Technically it's the image over a color rather than a color over the image, but the overall effect is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just use CSS.
Switch from `img` to `div` with `background-image: url("Your_url");` and then play with pseudo element.

Working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/atr9ckuu/).

```css
#img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400);
  position: relative;
}
#img:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: transparent;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
#img:hover:after {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
#img:hover > span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="img">
  <span>My text</span>
</div>
```